# Srisaila Khandam - Skanda Purana

Tags: puranas, translation-request, skanda-purana

I heard that Skanda Puranam contains a very large section called Srisaila Khandam describing about the famous kshetra [Srisailam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srisailam) which has the story of a Brahmana called Parvata doing tapas for Siva etc. Is the text of that khanda available in any language (preferably in sanskrit) ?

Comment: Many Khandas (which mention temples of south) of Skanda Purana are not available online. As far as i know, only Sahyadri Khanda is available.